# CSS div dynamic width with two values

Tags: html, css

I'd like my div to be 175px width if the text inside is shorter than this value or to take 100% of cointainer width if the text is bigger than 175px. How can I achieve this?

So far I tried to play with width, min-width and max-width but can figure it out.

```css
.text-div {
  min-width: 175px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: dotted 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="text-div">
      Short Text
  </div>

  <div class="text-div">
      Loooooooooooooog Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1- ID can only be used once in HTML. If you are going to use it for more than one element, you should use class.

2 - What you want to do is that if the content length is wider than 175px, it should be as wide as the length of the content?

Comment: I think you will need javascript for this. CSS cannot detect width of the content.

Comment: @SerhanYavçin thanks I edited. In my actual layout there is only one text div but the text can change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hacky approximation using clamp(). You need an extra wrapper that has a shrink-to-fit behavior (I used float but you can consider `inline-block`). `100%` of the child width will refer to its own width since its parent is shrink-to-fit.

I use clamp and compare 100% with 175px.

If 100% > 175px we have `(100% - 175px)*10000` a big positive value clamped to `100vw`, your full width behavior (we have to hide the overflow)

If 100% < 175px we have `(100% - 175px)*10000` a big negative value clamped to `175px`

```css
#container {
  overflow:hidden;
}

.text-div {
  width: clamp(175px, (100% - 175px)*10000, 100vw);
  background:yellow;
  margin:5px;
}

.wrap {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="text-div">
      Short Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="text-div">
      Looooooooooooooooooooooooooong Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could achieve the desired result by adding some Javascript.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.text-div').forEach( div => {
  if(div.clientWidth > 175){
    div.classList.add('long-text');
  }else{
    div.classList.add('short-text');
  }
})
```

```css
.text-div {
  display: table;
  border: dotted 2px;
}
.short-text{
  width: 175px;
}
.long-text{
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="text-div">
      Short Text
  </div>

  <div class="text-div">
      Looooooooooooooooooooooooong Text
  </div>
</div>
```